# How to handle tasks that are canceled without triggering a cancellation itself?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to get tasks in C# to work for a specific use case but I'm not understanding how task continuation options affect the flow of tasks.

What I'm trying to do is get a series of tasks chained together with ContinueWith. This will look something like this:

A -> B -> C -> D

However, I want to include the option to short-circuit this in the event an error, so it should look like this:

A -> B -> C -> D -> X

So I put "OnlyOnRanToCompletion" as the task continuation option for each of the ContinueWith functions. Then, to catch the cancellation and return an error, I put a final task at the end of the chain with the task continuation option set to "OnlyOnCanceled".

The problem is that when this last block is hit, the continuation option is not met and the task then gets set to cancelled even if the original series of tasks was never cancelled.

What I want to happen is have A through D run, and if one of them results in a cancellation, skip the rest and run X. If A through D complete, the task shouldn't cancel. The solution needs to support an arbitrary number of continuations and will be created using LINQ.Expressions, so using async/await is probably not going to fly unless it's done creatively.

Some sample code that exhibits this is:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;

var t = Task.FromResult(1)
  .ContinueWith(
    x => x.Result + 1,
    token,
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
    TaskScheduler.Default)
  .ContinueWith(
    x => x.Result + 1,
    token,
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
    TaskScheduler.Default)
  .ContinueWith(
    x => -1,
    token,
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled,
    TaskScheduler.Default);
```

The expected behavior here would be to return 3, and the status not completed.

The actual result is that the task is cancelled.

How do I do this?

Also, I can't use `async` because my goal is to piggyback off TPL inside of something compiled from LINQ.Expressions so that it can evaluate asynchronously and handle errors at the end without throwing any exceptions.

Comment: You should really use `await`, rather than `ContinueWIth` to construct asynchronous workflows.  `await` is *much* easier to use, and has much more desirable default behaviors in numerous areas, particularly with respect to error handling, as you are seeing here.

Comment: I should add this to the question - I would if I was able to, but I can't. I'm using LINQ.Expressions to compile a small program that needs to run asynchronously, and I don't have access to that.

Comment: I *strongly* doubt that, but if you're not going to provide enough information about your actual problem, then people aren't going to be able to give you a good solution.

Comment: It's true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543468/async-lambda-to-expressionfunctask

Comment: A problem trivially circumvented by having a named async method and a lambda that simply calls it.  Again, if you don't describe your *actual* problem, then you're not going to be able to get good solutions for it.

Comment: @AnthonyS. It's probably no longer of any use, but I made a library which allows you to create async state machines from ordinary Linq.Expressions trees: https://github.com/avonwyss/bsn.AsyncLambdaExpression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - to get the last continuation to run regardless of whether or not the previous continuations completed and without setting the status to canceled do this:

1. Change the continuation option of the last continuation to `TaskContinuation.None` so that it always runs, so it won't cancel if it gets here with a status of completed.
2. Don't pass in a cancellation token to the last continuation because passing in a cancellation token that has been cancelled seems to have the effect of causing the continuation to cancel if it would have otherwise run without the token.

Answer (score 0):

See the remarks for `ContinueWith` for an explanation of this behavior:

> The returned Task will not be scheduled for execution until the current task has completed. If the criteria specified through the continuationOptions parameter are not met, the continuation task will be canceled instead of scheduled.

Since the criteria for your last `ContinueWith` call weren't met, the `Task` returned from that call was cancelled.